# What kind of beer would a Yoda Beer be?

Tags: beer-styles

Say Yoda brews in Dagobah before Luke's arrival. For my next batch I would like to make a "Yoda Beer", what kind of beer would Yoda brew? Ale? Lager? which variety?

Comment: "Swamp" themed beer is tricky. Historically, hot, wet swampy areas would have made wine from local fruit, instead of beer, since you can't grow grains in a swamp. If you're still set on doing it, a dirty looking Brown Ale would work.

Comment: I don't think closing this question is necessarily fair - This would be a perfectly reasonable question to propose on SciFi.SE.  How about moving it instead?